# image background - how to repeat image as background rather than stretch it

Tags: android, image, background, repeat, stretch

I have an image I want to use as a background to some layout.
the problem is the image contains a texture of slant lines, so if i use a 1 pixel width image or a 9 patch the image is stretched and the texture is Twitching, so i can see the slant lines as latitude lines.
I saw that he android emulator uses a similar texture in the progress bar indeterminate animation, is there a special/simple definition to order the background image to repeat itself rather than stretch? is there a way to do it with 9 patch, cause eventualy i also need the corners to be round.
thanks for the help.

Comment: Is this a question related to Android? If so, tag the question as such. If not, perhaps you could give a clue about what technology you're working with.

Answer (score 29):

You would probably want to take a look at tile mode as Xandy answered. Here is some code for your reference which is used by me.

**repeat.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/img"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/repeat">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is it possible to set separate drawable for left corner, right corner and fill-in the background of a layout?

Answer (score 6):

use [android:tileMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#attr_android:tileMode).